# How to end client relationship?

Tags: difficult-client

I have a client who haggles too much on price and does not want to pay for revisions time to time and I want to end the relationship, however there is an ongoing project at this point and it is almost finished.

I'd like to finish the project, get paid, provide support for a couple months (as my contract states) and before ending the relationship:

- I want to give a heads up to the client before 3 months until my contract expires so they can find my replacement,
- I will offer a 4 hours of free handholding for the new developer - more than 4 hours will be billed,
- Send the client the whole source code
- End the relationship starting with an e-mail and following up with a conference call.

And then firmly end the relationship at the time of contract expiration.

However, the client is a small business and I don't know whether they can find a replacement in 3 months.
I think it is more than fair to give a heads up 3 months before though.

Am I approaching the situation professionally?
I don't usually fire clients often but this particular client is taking much of my time without a good return.

Should I take a different approach?
What is your take on it?

Best regards

Comment: Since the project is ending, won't the client relationship end anyway?

Comment: @morsor There is a 6 months techinal support added to the agreement

Answer (score 5):

1. You're being professional and fair.
2. Why would you give them 4 hours of free consulting? If they need and want your time to bring a new developer up to speed then they should pay for it. There's nothing untoward about billing them for your time.
3. How the client deals with this is their responsibility, not yours. If they can't find a suitable replacement within the timeframe that's their problem. You have no moral or ethical obligation to them.